# PayPal IPN and buyer address

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-sandbox

Somehow I can't get buyer address from the IPN response.

Here is request form:

```
          <form id="form1" name='frmPayPal' method="post" action="<?php echo $url; ?>">   
            <input type='hidden' name='business' value='<?php echo $ppAcc; ?>'>
            <input type='hidden' name='cmd' value='_xclick'>
            <input type='hidden' name='item_name' value='<?php echo $desc; ?>'>
            <input type='hidden' name='item_number' value='<?php echo $orderno; ?>'>
            <input type='hidden' name='amount' value='<?php echo $net = $price + $shipping; ?>' id='nettotal'>
            <input type='hidden' name='no_shipping' value='1'>
            <input type='hidden' name='currency_code' value='USD'>
            <input type='hidden' name='handling' value='0'>
            <input type='hidden' name='cancel_return' value='<?php echo $cancelURL; ?>'>

            <input type='hidden' name='return' value='<?php echo $returnURL; ?>'>
```

And response from PayPal IPN:

```
Array
(
    [0] => SUCCESS
    [1] => transaction_subject=Bookretary+-+Personal+Finance+Organizer
    [2] => payment_date=08%3A00%3A49+Nov+11%2C+2011+PST
    [3] => txn_type=web_accept
    [4] => last_name=User
    [5] => residence_country=US
    [6] => item_name=Bookretary+-+Personal+Finance+Organizer
    [7] => payment_gross=39.99
    [8] => mc_currency=USD
    [9] => business=seller_1320083112_biz%40interactmarketing.com
    [10] => payment_type=instant
    [11] => protection_eligibility=Ineligible
    [12] => payer_status=verified
    [13] => tax=0.00
    [14] => payer_email=buyer_1320083080_per%40interactmarketing.com
    [15] => txn_id=7FS07838VX3650032
    [16] => quantity=1
    [17] => receiver_email=seller_1320083112_biz%40interactmarketing.com
    [18] => first_name=Test
    [19] => payer_id=FHC9HUXME54VQ
    [20] => receiver_id=WKJGSA3LXEPN6
    [21] => item_number=10001
    [22] => handling_amount=0.00
    [23] => payment_status=Completed
    [24] => payment_fee=1.46
    [25] => mc_fee=1.46
    [26] => shipping=0.00
    [27] => mc_gross=39.99
    [28] => custom=
    [29] => charset=windows-1252
    [30] => 
)
```

Do I have missed something?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you set `<input type="hidden" name="no_shipping" value="1">`. That means you won't get a shipping address back.
Ensure you set `<input type="hidden" name="no_shipping" value="2">` instead.

Comment: Nice. It works, almost. I have added also line <input type='hidden' name='address_override' value='1'> to read data from the form. In the PayPal account Ship To comes properly (data from the form) but IPN returns last and first name of the PP account owner and same is with the email address. No clue why.

Comment: What do you mean exactly? It still doesn't return it, or?

Comment: It returns but not those from the from (or Ship to) but owner of PP account

Comment: Are you referring to the billing address? That's impossible. Please post a copy of your (Sandbox) IPN data.